# SQL: get results, but add a column starting at number 2000

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm migrating data right now and I need to prepare it for the new applicatin. Here is my query:

```
SELECT pet.member_id, CONCAT(  'full_', pet.member_id,  '.', pet.image_ext ) AS post_thumbnail
FROM pet
WHERE pet.image_ext !=  ""
```

I need to add a column for an ID ... and the number needs to start at `2000` and increase.

How can I add that to this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT pet.member_id,
CONCAT(  'full_', pet.member_id,  '.', pet.image_ext ) AS post_thumbnail,
@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID
FROM pet, 
(SELECT @rownum := 1999) r
WHERE pet.image_ext !=  ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add one value with number 1999.
Or use:

```
ALTER TABLE blabla AUTO_INCREMENT=100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[{yourDb}].[dbo].[pet]', RESEED, 2000);
```

It will reseed  your identity column and start it from 2001.